# attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsexception

In my project, when I scroll too quickly, I get an error saying:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]:
attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x180a39900 0x1800a7f80 0x1809281a8 0x180928040 0x1000a3994 0x1000a2b30
0x10016e784 0x185f4c108 0x185790810 0x18578b89c 0x185727778
0x183136b2c 0x183131738 0x1831315f8 0x183130c94 0x1831309dc 0x183183770
0x180cae1e8 0x1809db1f8 0x1809f1634 0x1809f0d6c 0x1809eeac4 0x18091d680
0x181e2c088 0x185794d90 0x100183934 0x1804be8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It then returns me to the following code (highlighting the `NSDictionary *attributes` line towards the bottom):

```
- (NSDictionary *)attributesFromProperties{
    // Setup shadow attributes
    NSShadow *shadow = shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    if (self.shadowColor){
        shadow.shadowColor = self.shadowColor;
        shadow.shadowOffset = self.shadowOffset;
    } else {
        shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
        shadow.shadowColor = nil;
    }

    // Setup color attributes
    UIColor *color = self.textColor;
    if (!self.isEnabled){
        color = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    } else if (self.isHighlighted){
        color = self.highlightedTextColor;
    }

    // Setup paragraph attributes
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraph.alignment = self.textAlignment;

    // Create the dictionary
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName : self.font,
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName : color,
                                 NSShadowAttributeName : shadow,
                                 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraph,
                                 };
    return attributes;
}
```

This code is from [KILabel](https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel). Would anyone happen to know how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: debug it, print/inspect `self.font`, `color`, `shadow` and `paragraph` to see which value is nil and why!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR:** `self.highlightedTextColor` is `nil`. Set it to some color.

**Details:**

The code will crash with this message in three cases:

1. `self.font` is `nil`.
2. `self.textColor` is `nil` and `self.isEnabled` is `YES` and `self.isHighlighted` is `NO`.
3. `self.highlightedTextColor` is `nil` and `self.isEnabled` is `YES` and `self.isHighlighted` is `YES`.

Since `KILabel` extends `UILabel` which doesn't allow `nil` values for `textColor` and `font`, the problem is probably caused by `highlightedTextColor` (option 3).

Comment: @jape Just set `self.highlightedTextColor` to a non-nil value. You could also fix it in `KILabel` source either with a safer condition `else if (self.isHighlighted && self.highlightedTextColor) {` or by providing a default `highlightedTextColor`, e.g. `- (UIColor *)highlightedTextColor { return [super highlightedTextColor] ?: [UIColor yellowColor]; }`

Comment: Thank you! Would it be harmful to do the conditional statement and provide a default color, or is that meaningless?

Comment: @jape meaningless. You don't need to check for `nil` if you know the variable is never `nil`.